# Let $f(x) = 2x + 3$ and $g(x) = ax + b$. If $f(g(x)) = x$ for all $x$, determine $a$ and $b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is what I know:

$f(x) = 2x + 3$

$g(x) = ax+b$

$f(g(x)) = 2(ax+b) + 3 = x$

I am just not too sure what to do next to find $a$ and $b$.

Comment: $2ax + 2b + 3 =x$. Therefore, $2a = 1 $ and $2b + 3 =0.$ You can take it from there.

Comment: Your last line then reads - $x(2a)+(2b+3) = x$, so comparing the coefficients of x and constant terms, we get $2a=1$ and since there is no constant term on the R.H.S so, $2b+3 = 0$, so you get two equations for $a$ and $b$ which we can solve and obtain the values of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: You maybe haven’t equated coefficients before, the reason we can do this is since iif they were different you would have a non-zero linear equation with infinite solutions which contradicts the fundamental theorem of algebra.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, we have $f(g(x)) = 2ax + 2b + 3 = x$. This is only true if $2a = 1$ and $2b + 3 = 0$, otherwise the equality wouldn't hold. Solving those, we get that $a = \dfrac{1}{2}$ and $b = -\dfrac{3}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $$f(g(x))=x$$ for all $x$, it is true also for $x=0$:  $$2b+3=f(b)=f(g(0))=0$$

and the same is true for $x=1$:

$$ 1= f(g(1))= f(a+b) = 2(a+b)+3$$